# Ajax Action Link wont't update div

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my sample code in Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<GridViewTest.Models.TabelaModel>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="tabela">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Druzyna)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LiczbaMeczy)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LiczbaGoliStrzelonych)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Druzyna)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LiczbaMeczy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LiczbaGoliStrzelonych)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }, new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "tabela", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
</div>
```

My intention is replace div "tabela" content when someone will click on "Edit" ajax action link, but when i do that, I'am redireting to "edit" view. "Edit" view is a partial view.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string grupa = "a";

        if (TempData["grupa"] != null)
        {
            grupa = TempData["grupa"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            grupa = "B";
        }

        string query = "Select * From LigaMistrzowGrupy where Grupa = @Grupa";
        List<TabelaModel> tabela = tabelaFunckje.wczytajTabele(query, grupa).ToList();

        return View(tabela);
    }

 [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult Edit()
    {
        return PartialView("_GridViewTabelaEdit");
    }
```

Could You tell what I'am doing wrong ?. I'am new in MVC.

Comment: Have you tried changing public PartialViewResult Edit() to public ActionResult  Edit()

Comment: Yes, but still nothing :/

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js or jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js to your page (and jquery also).
It's an avalaible nugget package.